# VBA to create Mapinfo table & points

Tags: vba, mapinfo

not very good at VBA, just in the basics so got stuck at below idea.

I want a VBA to create a MapInfo Tab file and points with Legend from a table in excel with given coordinates and legend based on another column.

searched a lot online, but couldn't find more than the below.

CreateObject("MapInfo.Application")

Please guide me to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this.

First option is to open MapInfo application (with `CreateObject("MapInfo.Application")`) and create TAB file there. However, this would be basically to write an MapBasic program, VBA would be only used to start MapInfo.

The second options is to create a MIF/MID file. These are two plain text files which can be imported into MapInfo. At [this page](https://support.pitneybowes.com/SearchArticles/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000PONMCA4&popup=false&lang=en_US) Pitney Bowes states *"We do publish the MapInfo Interchange Format (MIF\MID) files in our documentation"*, however you find it in Chapter 13 at normal [MapInfo User Guide](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/17.0/MapInfoProUserGuide.pdf).

I would recommend the second option. Creating two plain text files in VBA should be feasible. A good starting point would be to create a TAB file manually and export this TAB file as MIF/MID, then you have a valid example file.